# Unable to satisfy dependency of a Maven project, Eclipse Paho, using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, repository, paho

Now I'm trying to build a Maven project, Eclipse-Paho, using IntelliJ IDEA (Community 2018.1 version).
I downloaded the project files from Git hub:
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java. After creating a new Maven project with existing source, I first tried trying clean the root project, 'Eclipse Paho'. Then, the clean process finished with exit code 1, and I've got the following console logs:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/chad1231/Desktop/workspace/GeneralStudy/mqtt-maven/paho.mqtt.java -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.3/libexec -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.3/libexec/bin/m2.conf "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=56406:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.3/libexec/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.1.3 clean -f pom.xml -P eclipse-sign,create_gpg_signature
objc[1629]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1006a24c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10072d4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 11 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 11 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[WARNING] No explicit target runtime environment configuration. Build is platform dependent.
[WARNING] No explicit target runtime environment configuration. Build is platform dependent.
[WARNING] No explicit target runtime environment configuration. Build is platform dependent.
[WARNING] No explicit target runtime environment configuration. Build is platform dependent.
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0 @ /Users/chad1231/Desktop/workspace/GeneralStudy/mqtt-maven/paho.mqtt.java/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/pom.xml
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/201402280900/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/201309270900/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/201306260900/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/kepler/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0 @ /Users/chad1231/Desktop/workspace/GeneralStudy/mqtt-maven/paho.mqtt.java/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving class path of MavenProject: org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0 @ /Users/chad1231/Desktop/workspace/GeneralStudy/mqtt-maven/paho.mqtt.java/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/pom.xml
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature:1.2.0 @ /Users/chad1231/Desktop/workspace/GeneralStudy/mqtt-maven/paho.mqtt.java/org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature/pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature:1.2.0 @ /Users/chad1231/Desktop/workspace/GeneralStudy/mqtt-maven/paho.mqtt.java/org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature/pom.xml
May 15, 2018 5:48:32 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
May 15, 2018 5:48:32 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
May 15, 2018 5:48:37 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
May 15, 2018 5:48:37 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
May 15, 2018 5:48:50 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
May 15, 2018 5:48:50 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
[INFO] Fetching &countryCode=us&timeZone=9&format=xml from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?format=xml&file=/releases/kepler/201402280900/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching javax.annotation_1.1.0.v201209060031.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 20.05kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar.pack.gz from http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 63.94kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 420.3kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (94.24kB of 420.3kB at 90.24kB/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (218.92kB of 420.3kB at 84kB/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (314.83kB of 420.3kB at 86.64kB/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (415.47kB of 420.3kB at 82.53kB/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.apache.batik.css_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 67.24kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.apache.batik.util_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar.pack.gz from http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 43.94kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.1.v200903091627.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 18.5kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar.pack.gz from http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 27.84kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.apache.batik.util.gui_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar.pack.gz from http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 66.2kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20130513-1956.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 31.36kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.100.v20130515-1857.jar.pack.gz from http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 35.87kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505.jar.pack.gz from http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 43.57kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.200.v20130326-1255.jar.pack.gz from http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 34.79kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.100.v20130422-1538.jar.pack.gz from http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 48.99kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.301.v20130717-1549.jar.pack.gz from http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 67.99kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.4.1.v20130515-1857.jar.pack.gz from http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 52.39kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.1.v20130515-1857.jar.pack.gz from http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 67.32kB at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.4.200.v20130515-1857.jar.pack.gz from http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/ (0B of 37.39kB at 0B/s)
[ERROR] An error occurred while transferring artifact packed: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.icu,50.1.1.v201304230130 from repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler:
[ERROR]    Retry another mirror:
[ERROR]       Unable to connect to repository http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/eclipse/releases/kepler/201402280900/plugins/com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar.pack.gz
[ERROR] Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider$MirroringFailedException: Could not mirror artifact osgi.bundle,com.ibm.icu,50.1.1.v201304230130 into the local Maven repository.See log output for details. Connection to http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn refused: No route to host -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider$MirroringFailedException: Could not mirror artifact osgi.bundle,com.ibm.icu,50.1.1.v201304230130 into the local Maven repository.See log output for details.
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider$MirroringFailedException: Could not mirror artifact osgi.bundle,com.ibm.icu,50.1.1.v201304230130 into the local Maven repository.See log output for details.
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.downloadArtifact (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.makeOneFormatLocallyAvailable (PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.makeLocallyAvailable (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.getArtifactFile (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.provider.CompositeArtifactProvider.getArtifactFile (CompositeArtifactProvider.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformImpl.getLocalArtifactFile (TargetPlatformImpl.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.addUnit (P2ResolverImpl.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.toResolutionResult (P2ResolverImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolveDependencies (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject (DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open (AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open (AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect (DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute (DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute (AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute (AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect (HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams (HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest (AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest (AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest (MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest (FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.readInto (FileReader.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download (RepositoryTransport.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download (RepositoryTransport.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact (SimpleArtifactRepository.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact (SimpleArtifactRepository.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getRawArtifact (SimpleArtifactRepository.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.getRawOrNormalArtifact (CompositeArtifactRepository.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.getRawArtifact (CompositeArtifactRepository.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getRawArtifactFromRepository (RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getRawArtifactFromAnySource (RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.provider.CompositeArtifactProviderBaseImpl.getRawArtifact (CompositeArtifactProviderBaseImpl.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.downloadRawArtifact (PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.downloadMostSpecificNeededFormatOfArtifact (PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.downloadArtifact (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.makeOneFormatLocallyAvailable (PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.makeLocallyAvailable (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.getArtifactFile (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.provider.CompositeArtifactProvider.getArtifactFile (CompositeArtifactProvider.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformImpl.getLocalArtifactFile (TargetPlatformImpl.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.addUnit (P2ResolverImpl.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.toResolutionResult (P2ResolverImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolveDependencies (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject (DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.connectSocket (ECFHttpClientProtocolSocketFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open (AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open (AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect (DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute (DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute (AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute (AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect (HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams (HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest (AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest (AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest (MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest (FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.readInto (FileReader.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download (RepositoryTransport.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download (RepositoryTransport.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact (SimpleArtifactRepository.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact (SimpleArtifactRepository.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getRawArtifact (SimpleArtifactRepository.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.getRawOrNormalArtifact (CompositeArtifactRepository.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.CompositeArtifactRepository.getRawArtifact (CompositeArtifactRepository.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getRawArtifactFromRepository (RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getRawArtifactFromAnySource (RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.provider.CompositeArtifactProviderBaseImpl.getRawArtifact (CompositeArtifactProviderBaseImpl.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.downloadRawArtifact (PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.downloadMostSpecificNeededFormatOfArtifact (PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.downloadArtifact (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.makeOneFormatLocallyAvailable (PackedFormatMirroringArtifactProvider.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.makeLocallyAvailable (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.local.MirroringArtifactProvider.getArtifactFile (MirroringArtifactProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.provider.CompositeArtifactProvider.getArtifactFile (CompositeArtifactProvider.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.target.TargetPlatformImpl.getLocalArtifactFile (TargetPlatformImpl.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.addUnit (P2ResolverImpl.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.toResolutionResult (P2ResolverImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies (P2ResolverImpl.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolveDependencies (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies (P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject (DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead (TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In addition to this log, I found Maven Model Inspection on the whole project returns 9 errors and all the errors come from 'pom.xml' files. Out of the 9 errors, 4 errors say 'Unable to satisfy dependency from ...' such as:

> No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to
>   satisfy dependency from
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.2.0 to
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.view 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy
>   dependency from org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature.feature.group
>   1.2.0 to org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 0.0.0.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]

So I compared these errors and the console logs and found that dependency resolution processes of the unsatisfied dependencies caused I/O exceptions such as:

```
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature:1.2.0 @ /Users/chad1231/Desktop/workspace/GeneralStudy/mqtt-maven/paho.mqtt.java/org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.feature/pom.xml
May 15, 2018 6:02:33 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
May 15, 2018 6:02:33 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

I assume this implies the project build is not properly done due to some repository reference issue. I suspected firewall first, but turning off the firewall doesn't help. What should I do to solve this build problem?

Comment: Looks like some network issue. Is it possible to open "http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn" in browser? Does mvn clean work from terminal?

Comment: @y.bedrov Thx for your comment. The mirror site is reachable, and mvn clean at terminal gives the same error message.

Comment: Do you use firewall or proxy?

Comment: @y.bedrov Nope, as I mentioned in the end of the post, I tried turning off the firewall, but it didn't help..

Comment: Just to ensure - did you use terminal outside IDE to run "mvn clean" command which gave you the same error message?

Comment: @y.bedrov yap.. tried that command and got the same error message..